# Using ggplot2 why does changing the color palette result in all grey?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Built into my app I have the ability to change the color palette including for color vision deficiencies. However, one of my graphs works fine with the R4 but is all grey with the Okabe-Ito palette and lists the colors' names in the legend. What am I doing wrong?

```
data<-as.data.frame(rbind(15.29,84.71))
         data<-cbind(x=c("Total Measurement Variance","Total Measurement Variance"),y=data,Group=c("Repeatability","Reproducibility"))
         colnames(data)<-c("x","y","Source")

color=palette.colors(n = 8,palette = "R4")

p<-ggplot(data=data,aes(x=x,y=y,fill=Source,label=y))+
     geom_bar(stat="identity")+
     geom_label(aes(group=Source),fill="white",label=paste0(data$y,"%"),position=position_stack(vjust=.5))+
     scale_y_continuous(labels=function (x) paste0(x,"%"))+
     scale_fill_manual(values=color[-1])+
     labs(title="Components of Variation",x="",y="% of Measurement Error Variance")
p

color=palette.colors(n = 8,palette = "Okabe-Ito")

p<-ggplot(data=data,aes(x=x,y=y,fill=Source,label=y))+
     geom_bar(stat="identity")+
     geom_label(aes(group=Source),fill="white",label=paste0(data$y,"%"),position=position_stack(vjust=.5))+
     scale_y_continuous(labels=function (x) paste0(x,"%"))+
     scale_fill_manual(values=color[-1])+
     labs(title="Components of Variation",x="",y="% of Measurement Error Variance")
p
```

Comment: Use `color=unname(palette.colors(n = 8,palette = "Okabe-Ito"))`. it's not clear why one version of `palette.colors` returns a named vector and the other returns an unnamed vector, but you want an unnamed one when using `scale_fill_manual(values=)`

Comment: Wow, I never would have figured that out. @MrFlick thanks for the very quick answer!

Comment: As a side-note to MrFlick's comment, a named `values` argument tries to match up the names with the unique values of the `fill = Source` column. Failing to match up these names, it just displays grey. In contrast, using an unnamed `values` argument just matches the colours to unique values in `fill = Source` in order in which they appear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that for some reason, `palette.colors` returns a named vector when you use `palette = "Okabe-Ito"` Compare the output here

```
palette.colors(n = 8,palette = "R4")
# [1] "#000000" "#DF536B" "#61D04F" "#2297E6" "#28E2E5" "#CD0BBC"
# [7] "#F5C710" "#9E9E9E"

palette.colors(n = 8,palette = "Okabe-Ito")
#         black        orange       skyblue   bluishgreen 
#     "#000000"     "#E69F00"     "#56B4E9"     "#009E73" 
#        yellow          blue    vermillion reddishpurple 
#     "#F0E442"     "#0072B2"     "#D55E00"     "#CC79A7"
```

When you use `scale_fill_manual(values=)`, if you pass a named vector, then it will try to match up the names of in the color vector to the names of the levels of your factor. Since your `Source` values are "Repeatability" and "Reproducibility" and not values like "orange" and "skyblue", the matching doesn't work and you just get grey. If you remove the names, then it won't try to do the matching.

```
color <- unname(palette.colors(n = 8, palette = "Okabe-Ito"))
```

should work